# Are there any good documentations / books / tutorials for xUnit.NET?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net

On my search for a Unit-Testing tool for C# i have found xUnit.NET. Untill now, i read most of the articles on [http://xunit.codeplex.com/](http://xunit.codeplex.com//) and even tried out the examples given at [How do I use xUnit.net?](http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HowToUse&referringTitle=Home).

But sadly, on the offical page i could just find the basic informations to xUnit.NET. Is there any further information avadible for it?

Comment: "Is there any further information avadible for it?" What specifically do you want to know? What have you managed to achieve with it so far?

Comment: The *.chm file is very comprehensive.  You have to grab it separately from the project's [downloads page](http://xunit.codeplex.com/releases/view/77573).

Comment: Untill now i got nothing more, than the examples at "How do I use xUnit.net" to work. 

What I'm looking for, is a good text to learn to work with the framework.

Comment: It's probably not established enough for there to be any books yet. A book like [Pragmatic Unit Testing](http://pragprog.com/book/utc2/pragmatic-unit-testing-in-c-with-nunit) will cover the general concepts, though, even if the concrete examples are all for xUnit.NET's predecessor.

Comment: Thanks for your answers - especially the *.chm-File will help a lot. I  think its hard to understand xUnit.NET with a general book about unit tests, becaus the terms and useage differ a lot from other xUnit-Frameworks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Besides the [xUnit-1.9.1.chm-File](http://xunit.codeplex.com/downloads/get/423829) mentioned by Sean U and the [Examples on the official xUnit.NET website](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-desktop) I found two other resources to help me understand the basics of the work with xUnit.NET:

- [An Introduction to xUnit.net for ASP.NET MVC Developers](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/06/30/an-introduction-to-the-xunit-net-testing-framework-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx) by Stephen Walter
- [Learning to Use xUnit.Net](https://nearsoft.com/?s=xunit) (3 Chapter Tutorial) by Maria Marcano

Sadly, as pointed out also by Sean U, it seems as there are no books at all about the xUnit.NET-Framework yet. So, for further information it looks like one has go with studying the *.chm-File and reading general books about unit testing. Or switch to another testing-framework, that's what I think I'll do...

**Update**

Ognyan Dimitrov added some additional resources in his comments:

- [XUnitPatterns.com](http://xunitpatterns.com/index.html)  by Gerard Meszaros (Website)
- [xUnit Test Patterns: Refactoring Test Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131495054) by Gerard Meszaros (Book)

Comment: +1 for a solid link to the .CHM file which is extremely well hidden for some reason.

Comment: Other resources : [this](http://lostechies.com), [this](http://www.amazon.com/xUnit-Test-Patterns-Refactoring-Code/dp/0131495054) and [this](http://xunitpatterns.com/index.html). These should be sufficient to start with.

Comment: @ I added two of the links you recommended to the answer, but I could not find anything xUnit related on [lostechies.com](http://lostechies.com/)

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to abandon xUnit and use NUnit instead, a good book to read is ["The Art of Unit Testing (with examples in .NET)"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988274).

Nice clear explanations of both basic and advanced unit testing concepts, using the NUnit framework.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I have already worked through that book and it was indeed quite helpful.